# Attributes precedent in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I read in [Chef site](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html) that for default attributes specified in environment takes higher precedence than default attributes specified in roles. This makes sense as we may have different web-server for development, testing and production.

But in case of override attribute this is reverse i.e override attributes of roles takes precedence over override attribute of roles. I am not able to guess reason behind this ? Can anyone please explain me why chef chose such precedence ordering.

I am also adding complete list of  attribute precedence as given in chef site

- The `default` attribute specified in a **cookbook attribute file**.
- The `default` attribute specified in a **recipe**.
- The `default` attribute specified in an **environment**.
- The `default` attribute specified in a **role**.
- The `force_default` attribute specified in a**a cookbook attribute file**.
- The `force_default` attribute specified in a **recipe**.
- The `normal` attribute specified in a **cookbook attribute file**.
- The `normal` attribute specified in a **recipe**.
- The `override attribute` specified in a **cookbook attribute file**.
- The `override attribute` specified in a **recipe**.
- The `override attribute` specified in a **role**.
- The `override attribute` specified in an **environment**.
- The `force_override` attribute specified in a **cookbook attribute file**.
- The `force_override` attribute specified in a **recipe**.
- The `automatic` attribute collected during the **Ohai run**.

Thanks

Comment: This is not the right place to ask "why?" questions like this. You are welcome to jump on IRC and ask there though.

Comment: It's the other way around. The `default` attributes set on a role take higher precedence over the ones set on the environment -- i.e. if you set the same default on both the role and the environment, the one on the role wins.

The opposite is true for `override` attributes. If you override an attribute on the environment, it will win over the overrides set elsewhere, including on roles.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for the override order is on the site you link to.  Just be clear though, because it's a common confusion, precedence in that documentation is referring to the order in which values are fed to the evaluation sequence.  Because the evaluation is in a overwrite form, the lowest precedence values are the ones that you get after evaluation is complete.  Thus there is no way to override Ohai supplied values.

> The attribute precedence order for roles and environments is reversed
>   for default and override attributes. The precedence order for default
>   attributes is environment, then role. The precedence order for
>   override attributes is role, then environment. Applying environment
>   override attributes after role override attributes allows the same
>   role to be used across multiple environments, yet ensuring that values
>   can be set that are specific to each environment (when required). For
>   example, the role for an application server may exist in all
>   environments, yet one environment may use a database server that is
>   different from other environments.

As to the why of the default doesn't use the same logic as override, I don't know.